# Node.js app runs well on local host but shows error when deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, mongoose

Below is the code for my index.js file. I have used mongoose for database connection. Every time I try running app it shows error at get method. Process terminate with error of no child process.

```
    `import express from 'express';
     import mongoose from 'mongoose';
     import bodyparser from 'body-parser';
     import cors from 'cors';
     import history from 'connect-history-api-fallback';
     import routes from './routes/RecruitmentRoutes';
     import routes1 from './routes/RecruitmentRoutes2';
     import deleteRoutes from './routes/deleteRoutes'

     var mongodb = require('mongodb');
     var path = require('path'); 
     const app = express();



   //mongo connection

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://csci202:Olemiss@2020@cluster0-x0tez.mongodb.net/test? 
    retryWrites=true&w=majority',{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))


    //bodyparser setup

    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
    app.use(bodyparser.json());


    app.use(cors());
    app.use(history({verbose:true}))
    const PORT = 4000;

    routes(app);
    routes1(app);
    deleteRoutes(app);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'build')));




    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname),'build','index.html');
    res.redirect('/');
    })


    app.listen(PORT,()=>{

    console.log('Recruitment server running on port ')
    })`
```

Below is the screenshot for the error.[image: Screenshot for heroku logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port defined in Heroku is stored in the environment variable `process.env.PORT`. You need to change your code to use that. How? Change the PORT variable declaration, instead of this:

```
const PORT = 4000;
```

Use this:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000
```

That line uses the `process.env.PORT` environment variable if it is defined (and that is, on Heroku), and uses `4000` if is not defined (that means, on your local machine).